# showing npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT when I try create react app

Tags: reactjs

I got this error :
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Quarter\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-27T14_25_32_964Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting firstapp/ from E:\UMS\Web Development\React
Done.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\UMS\Web Development\React
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-react-app firstapp

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Quarter\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-27T14_25_18_551Z-debug-0.log

i tried to run this code :
npm init react-app firstapp

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading nodejs version to v 16.x